# How to add new attributes to Access-Accept FreeRadius

Tags: freeradius, radius

I'm using freeradius 2.2.5, I want to add the `cisco-avpair` attribute to `Access-Accept`. In the raddb folder, I did not find the config file for it like `Access-Reject` (it has a file is attrs.access-reject).

Can you help me where is file can update for it? Thank you very much.